# Summarise groups across columns and rows

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe `df` where:

```
 Year      Score    x1   x2   x3 
 2006      102      K    P    8   
 2006      89       L    K    P   
 2006      46       P    3    0   
 2007      76       L    2    1  
 2007      29       L    K    6   
 2008      690      P    4    4   
 2008      301      K    0    1   
 ...       ...      ..   ..   ..
```

However, I would like it to look like this:

```
 Year     K    P    L    K_prop  P_prop  L_prop 
 2006     191  191  135  0.37    0.37    0.26    
 2007     29        105  0.22            0.78
 2008     301  690       0.30    0.70
 ...      ..   ..   ..   ..      ..      ..
```

Where each `x` becomes a column containing the sum of that column grouped by year. I would also like another column representing each of the respective column's proportion of the total score.

`K_prop = K/(K+P+L)` ; `P_prop = P/(K+P+L)` ; `L_prop = L/(K+P+L)`

I am sorry if this is not descriptive enough, but I appreciate any and all help you have to offer!

Comment: Is the expectedd output based on the input showed

Comment: I think if you explain how `K_prop`, `P_prop`, and `L_prop` should be calculated someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Hi sorry, K_prop = K/(K+P+L) respectively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` do the calculation and reshape it back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('x')) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(value, '[A-Za-z]')) %>% 
    group_by(Year, value) %>%
    summarise(Score = sum(Score)) %>%
    ungroup %>%        
    group_by(Year) %>%
    mutate(prop = Score/sum(Score)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = c(Score, prop))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Year [3]
#   Year Score_K Score_L Score_P prop_K prop_L prop_P
#  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  2006     191      89     237  0.369  0.172  0.458
#2  2007      29     105      NA  0.216  0.784 NA    
#3  2008     301      NA     690  0.304 NA      0.696
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2008L), Score = c(102L, 89L, 46L, 76L, 29L, 690L, 301L), x1 = c("K", 
"L", "P", "L", "L", "P", "K"), x2 = c("P", "K", "3", "2", "K", 
"4", "0"), x3 = c("8", "P", "0", "1", "6", "4", "1")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This structure looks correct, but I am getting values like <dbl [1]> and <NULL> in the new columns. Any thoughts?

Comment: @keaton is the expected output based on the input showed as I was thinking that the `...` means you have emore data

Comment: Yes. I do have more data (years 2006-2016 with over 300,000 rows). Could that be an issue?

Comment: @keaton not an issue.  If you can `dput` the example  i.e 10-15 rows in your post with the correct expected output, it is easier to crosscheck

Comment: @keaton in the example you showed, I am not getting  'P' =191 for 2006

Comment: that did it!! amazing akrun!!